# Is a cast from float to double and back to float (that's not optimized away) guaranteed to return the same value?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point

```
float x=something();             // set by something that returns float
double x_double = x;             // cast to double
// Assume no optimization can happen across this barrier
float x_float = x_double;        // cast to float
```

Is it guaranteed that x==x_float ?

EDIT: commentator makes the good point that x!=x_float if is_nan(x). However, it should be guaranteed that is_nan(x) == is_nan(x_float)?

Comment: `x==x` would not be true for `x=NaN`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting between int, float and double in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355213/casting-between-int-float-and-double-in-c)

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36840390.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed.

§6.2.5 (Types) para 10:

> 10. There are three real floating types, designated as **float**, **double**, and **long double**. The set of values of the type **float** is a subset of the set of values of the type **double**…

§6.3.1.5 (Conversions of real floating types) para 1:

> 1. When a value of real floating type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged.

Since the values of `float` are a subset of the values of `double`, the `float`'s value can be represented exactly as a `double` so it is unchanged. The resulting `double` therefore has an exact `float` representation so it will be converted back unchanged.

As has been pointed out, the fact that the value is unchanged does not mean it will compare equal since it might be a NaN. But both or neither will be NaN.